# Best way to restrict mobile device by IP address in APACHE

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I used restrict based on IP to allow only few device to access my site.
I used following code in htaccess file:

```
deny from All
alloy from xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

This was working fine and I was able to access the site only from my mobile device. But after sometime my mobile's IP address changed and I was not able to access the site from my device.

So, is there any foolproof method to restrict a site access to certain device even if its IP changes?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are pretty slim in that regard. You best bet for ensuring access only for you is to set up a VPN or ssh tunnel. Apache doesn't provide a way to filter based on MAC address (sounds like what you're asking), which isn't a secure option anyways.

Another choice would be to set up an authentication page for access only to you. This way you can have your site live to the world without having to go in and edit .htaccess every time your IP changes, which can happen at any point. See this link for further elaboration: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26156/make-a-web-server-accessible-only-to-specific-mac-addresses